# visual c# multiple browser windows with separate sessions

Tags: c#

I have a problem with visual c# browsers.

I have 2 browsers.  I logged in a website from one browser, and the tried to log in same website with another account on the other browser, but i was already logged in with the account i used on browser 1. I tried sepirating browsers with different froms, but it was still the same thing.

Any one knows how to fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using standalone browsers or WebBrowser control in a WinForm?

Comment: I am using WebBrowser control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to end browser session before navigating second browser, and you can do it via Windows API.

First declare an API function like this:

```
private const int INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION = 42;

[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);
```

And then before using second browser - call it like this:

```
InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

And only then Navigate the second browser.

Comment: It did work, yet it logged me out of the account i was in on browser1. Is there a way to keep both browsers logged in same website with dif accounts ?

Comment: I think you will have to compromise. Either share sessions or ending one will end another